# SQL запрос для возвращения части текста

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день! Пишу Sql запрос. В поле `ticket_history`.`name` хранится название поля, его старое и новое значение: `%%FieldName%%FaqID%%Value%%2%%OldValue%%1`.
Необходимо возвращать только новое значение Value.

С помощью функции TRIM удаляю повторяющееся начало, а как можно удалить `%%OldValue%%` и все, что после него следует? Спасибо!

```
    SELECT
          TRIM(
LEADING '%%FieldName%%FaqID%%Value%%' 
FROM 
TRIM(
TRAILING '%%OldValue%%' 
FROM `ticket_history`.`name`)),
         `ticket_history`.`change_time`,
         `users`.`first_name`,
         `users`.`last_name`
    FROM
         `users` INNER JOIN `ticket_history` ON `users`.`id` = `ticket_history`.`change_by`
    WHERE
         `ticket_history`.`history_type_id` = 28
```

Comment: посмотрите в сторону решения - https://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/

Comment: @ВадимГорбачев Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы не стал пользоваться регэкспами в такой задаче. Тут достаточно простого поиска подстроки:

```
SELECT name, SUBSTR(name, 28, INSTR(name, '%%OldValue%%')-28)Value
FROM(
  SELECT '%%FieldName%%FaqID%%Value%%20000%%OldValue%%10' as name
  UNION ALL SELECT '%%FieldName%%FaqID%%Value%%-12%%OldValue%%-999'
  UNION ALL SELECT '%%FieldName%%FaqID%%Value%%ABCDEF%%OldValue%%G'
)T
```

результат:

```
name                                            Value
%%FieldName%%FaqID%%Value%%20000%%OldValue%%10  20000
%%FieldName%%FaqID%%Value%%-12%%OldValue%%-999  -12
%%FieldName%%FaqID%%Value%%ABCDEF%%OldValue%%G  ABCDEF
```

Если же вам не нравится использование числовых констант в запросе, можно вычислить отдельно длину строки `'%%FieldName%%FaqID%%Value%%'`:

```
SELECT name, SUBSTR(name, len_pref+1, INSTR(name, '%%OldValue%%')-(len_pref+1))Value
FROM(
  SELECT '%%FieldName%%FaqID%%Value%%20000%%OldValue%%10' as name
  UNION ALL SELECT '%%FieldName%%FaqID%%Value%%-12%%OldValue%%-999'
  UNION ALL SELECT '%%FieldName%%FaqID%%Value%%ABCDEF%%OldValue%%G'
)T1,(
  SELECT LENGTH('%%FieldName%%FaqID%%Value%%') as len_pref
)T2
```